# Polling MongoDB every 3 seconds

Tags: java, mongodb

I have written a sample MongoDB database poller, which continosly polls the database every 3 seconds.

While querying the database,  can I use the same cursor every time as the query  or should I fetch new one each time and close that accordingly?

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoURI;

    public class Data extends Thread {
        static DB db = getConnection("");
        DBCollection table = db.getCollection("stock");
        DBCursor cursor = null;

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    ArrayList<stocks> list = new ArrayList<stocks>();
                    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
                    table.setObjectClass(stocks.class);
                    cursor = table.find(searchQuery);
                    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                        stocks s = (stocks) cursor.next();
                        list.add(s);
                    }
                    cursor.close();
                    storeOrUpdate(list);
                    System.out.println("*****************");
                    Thread.sleep(3000);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Data d = new Data();
            d.start();

        }

    public static DB getConnection(String databaseName) {
        if (db == null) {
            System.out.println("===========================================");
            String textUri = "mongodb://krn1231:saibabagod1@ds043388.mongolab.com:43388/stocks";
            MongoURI uri = new MongoURI(textUri);
            Mongo m = null;
            try {
                m = new Mongo(uri);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            db = m.getDB("stocks");
            return db;
        } else {
            return db;
        }
    }

    public void storeOrUpdate(ArrayList<stocks> list) throws Exception {
        Connection connection = null;
        connection = ConexionTest.getConnection();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            stocks stoc = list.get(i);
            System.out.println(stoc.get("symbol"));

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb normally keeps a cursor open for about 20 minutes. So it is not a good idea to keep or ignore an open cursor since this will affect your performance. An ideal way to do this is close the cursor when you are done with your work. 
(The database will automatically close the cursor after 20 minutes if not used.)
So I would suggest closing the cursor and opening a new one every time.